# Binance API-key Trading Bot - InvalidNonce: binance {"code":-1021,"msg":"Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow."}

Tags: javascript, node.js, ccxt

I have re-created a Binance API-key trading bot which uses NodeJS, CCXT & Axios (It pulls the API+secret key from a .env file). I am getting the error when trying to execute the trading-bot;;

> PS C:\Users\mwalk\Documents\Crypto-Bot> node index.js
> C:\Users\mwalk\Documents\Crypto-Bot\node_modules\ccxt\js\base\Exchange.js:640
> throw new exact[string] (message)
> ^
>
> InvalidNonce: binance {"code":-1021,"msg":"Timestamp for this request
> is outside of the recvWindow."}
> at binance.throwExactlyMatchedException (C:\Users\mwalk\Documents\Crypto-Bot\node_modules\ccxt\js\base\Exchange.js:640:19)

```
require('dotenv').config();
const ccxt = require('ccxt');
const axios = require('axios');

const tick = async(config, binanceClient) => {
    const { asset, base, spread, allocation } = config
    const market = `${asset}/${base}`;

    const orders = await binanceClient.fetchOpenOrders(market);
    orders.forEach(async order => {
        await binanceClient.cancelOrder(order.id);
    });
        
    const results = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd'),
        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=tether&vs_currencies=usd')
    ]);
    const marketPrice = results [0].data.bitcoin.usd / results[1].data.tether.usd;
    
    const sellPrice = marketPrice * (1 + spread);
    const buyPrice = marketPrice * (1 - spread);
    const balances = await binanceClient.fetchBalance();
    const assetBalance = balances.free[asset];
    const baseBalance = balances.free[base];
    const sellVolume = assetBalance * allocation;
    const buyVolume = (baseBalance * allocation) / marketPrice;

    await binanceClient.createLimitSellOrder(market, sellVolume, sellPrice);
    await binanceClient.createLimitBuyOrder(market, buyVolume, buyPrice);

    console.log(`
        New tick for ${market}...
        Created limit sell order for ${sellVolume}@${sellPrice}
        Create limit buy order for ${buyVolume}@${buyPrice}
    
    `);

} 

const run = () => {
    const config = {
        asset: 'BTC',
        base: 'USDT',
        allocation: 0.1,
        spread: 0.1,
        tickInterval: 2000

    };
    const binanceClient = new ccxt.binance({
        apiKey: process.env.API_ENV,
        secret: process.env.API_SECRET
        
    });
   
    tick(config, binanceClient);
    setInterval(tick, config.tickInterval, config, binanceClient);

};

run();
```

Comment: Most operating systems (i.e. Windows, Mac, Linux) have an option to automatically synchronize the system clock periodically using an NTP (network time protocol) server:

Windows: Double-click the system clock and then click on the Internet Time tab.

Mac: Applications > System Preferences > Date & Time

Linux: System > Admin >Time and Date. More: https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/time-distribution/internet-time-service-its

Answer (score 0):

sync your pc time with nist option from your control panel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).